# Error occurs when debugging rust program with vscode (windows only)

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, vscode-debugger, apache-arrow

I am trying to debug the code below with vscode, but an error occurs.

Development environment

- Microsoft Windows 10 Home  10.0.19042 Build 19042
- rustc 1.49.0 (e1884a8e3 2020-12-29)
- Vscode 1.54.3
- CodeLLDB v1.6.1

```
// Cargo.toml
//[dependencies]
//datafusion = "3.0.0"
//arrow = "3.0.0"
//tokio = { version = "0.2", features = ["macros", "blocking", "rt-core", "rt-threaded", "sync"] }


use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use arrow::util::pretty;
use datafusion::error::Result;
use datafusion::prelude::*;

/// This example demonstrates executing a simple query against an Arrow data source (CSV) and
/// fetching results

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    println!("======== Start Program ========");
    let start = Instant::now();

    // let res_path = r"/root/workspace/project/hello_arrow/res/sample_01.csv";

    // http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html
    // listing_id,id,date,reviewer_id,reviewer_name,comments
    // Boston, Massachusetts, United States
    let res_path = r"D:\workspace\vscode\arrow_rust\res\review.01.csv";

    // create local execution context
    let mut ctx = ExecutionContext::new();
    // register csv file with the execution context
    ctx.register_csv("datatable_01", res_path, CsvReadOptions::new())?;

    // execute the query
    let sql = "SELECT count(id) from datatable_01";
    let df = ctx.sql(sql)?;
    let results = df.collect().await?;

    // print the results
    pretty::print_batches(&results)?;

    let duration = start.elapsed();

    println!("Time elapsed in expensive_function() is: {:?}", duration);
    println!("======== End Program ========");
    Ok(())
}
```

Error Code

```
configuration: {
  type: 'lldb',
  request: 'launch',
  name: 'Debug Window',
  program: '${workspaceRoot}/target/debug/arrow_rust.exe',
  args: [],
  cwd: '${workspaceRoot}',
  sourceLanguages: [ 'rust' ],
  __configurationTarget: 5,
  relativePathBase: 'd:\\workspace\\vscode\\arrow_rust'
}
Listening on port 8541
error: arrow_rust.exe :: Class 'arrow::datatypes::DataType' has a member '__0' of type 'alloc::vec::Vec<arrow::datatypes::Field>' which does not have a complete definition.
Debug adapter exit code=3221225620, signal=null.
```

The program runs normally. Debugging fine on Linux for the same code.

Is there any other way to debug on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem.
Inspired by the link below, I have solved it.

https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/issues/410#issuecomment-786791796

The reason is that I have installed **NVIDIA Nsight**.
As shown below, the **msdia140.dll for Nsight** has been loaded by codelldb.

[image: msdia140.dll]

Run PowerShell as administrator. Execute the command below to register the component. Then codelldb works.

```
regsvr32.exe C:\Users\【user name】\.vscode\extensions\vadimcn.vscode-lldb-1.6.8\lldb\bin\msdia140.dll
```

[image: PowerShell]

**Update**
For newer versions, the DLL has moved to another folder:

```
regsvr32.exe C:\Users\[user name]\.vscode\extensions\vadimcn.vscode-lldb-1.8.1\adapter\msdia140.dll
```

Comment: Thank you. I also installed NVIDIA Nsight. In my case, it is debuggable the same way.